# Remove jQuery effects if browser is certain size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive layout and utilising a handful of jQuery plugins, such as Tabs, Drop menu, scroll to top etc, one thing I'm struggling with is once the browser is in it's smallest position how to take away the jQuery magic?

Currently it's looking awful with the effects in a smaller view, so I'm just looking for a couple of pointers or a code example if you don't mind.

e.g. If there's a jQuery IF browser viewpoint is =< 320px then don't run etc?

I have done a bit of research first before posting here, hopefully an expert can assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it could be to try wrapping a width condition inside a [**$(window).resize**](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() <= 320) {
         // Leave empty
      }
      else {
        // Rest of your jQuery code can go here
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll certainly give this a try, all makes sense :)

Comment: @Codesworth No problem! Let me know if it's fixed or not, if not we can look at other solutions :) thanks

Comment: Hi,

I've noticed this only works when the page is loaded at x resolution - if the browser is resized it doesn't apply...

e.g. load at 320px and resize to 640px > Fine
     load at 640px and resize to 320px > Doesn't remove effect

Comment: I'll mark this as solved - as it does answer my question, i'll ask another for removing a function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();

    if(w <= 320) {
         // Run your script
    }
});
```

But I'd suggest you using CSS3 [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to build a responsive web design.

> A media query consists of a media type and at least one expression
>   that limits the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as
>   width, height, and color. Added in CSS3, media queries let the
>   presentation of content be tailored to a specific range of output
>   devices without having to change the content itself.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you - OK, great, great, i'm absolutely using CSS3 media queries, though mixing it with jQuery was proving troublesome

Comment: Hi,

I've noticed this only works when the page is loaded at x resolution - if the browser is resized it doesn't apply...

e.g. load at 320px and resize to 640px > Fine
     load at 640px and resize to 320px > Doesn't remove effect